# How to get detail user after login with laravel passport and show it using jquery

Tags: javascript, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I have some problem with my code, so I have method to login using laravel passport and it's work my token is show up and nothing error in my view, but I wanna ask after I have login, How can I show the detail user? I wanna use for showing the detail user, and also to insert back to database for knowing user activity (like change data, insert data, and deleting data). So first of All my code like this :

In Controller what I wanna call the detail user :

```
public function index() {
    $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
    dd($user) //<= when I look is null value
}
```

Controller Login :

```
public function login(Request $login) {
    $email = $login->email;
    $password = $login->password;

    $user = User::where('user.email', $email)->where('user.password', $password)->first();
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('myToken')->accessToken;
    return response()->json([
       'user' => $user,
       'token' => $success
    ]);
}
```

Route :

```
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
```

javascript :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});

$.ajax({
   url: "login",
   method: "POST",
   data: {
      email: email,
      password: password,
   },
}).done(function (data, status) {
   localStorage.setItem('myToken', data.token);
   $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
       jqxhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer" + data.token);
   });
}).fail(function (error) {
   //error in here
})
```

Comment: try with `$request->user()` here `$request` is object of Request in function `public function index(Request $request) ...`

Comment: thanks before sir, but still null value

Comment: please check request headers. also your `->where('user.password', $password)` is wrong you cannot directly compare password in DB like that. Please go through passport doc.

Comment: Done Sir, I already solve my problem